# Click Javascript link href

Tags: javascript, python, href, mechanize

Estoy haciendo un codigo para entrar a una plataforma. Tiene una URL la cual accedo y me logueo a traves de Mechanize.

```
import mechanize

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.addheaders = [('User-agent','Chrome')]
#URL del Login
br.open('https://platform.ttt/en/login')
br.select_form(nr=0)
#Info del Login, Buscar forms desde la pagina y donde dice 'username' ponemos el name cuando inspeccionamos en el browser!
br.form['username'] = 'martin@ttt'
br.form['password'] = 'martinttt'
#Logueate
sub = br.submit()
#Url logueado
print sub.geturl()
#Cambio de URL
br.open('https://ttt/en/users/inventory/43a05221-5760-4eba-a40d-087856e79fbb/general')
print br.geturl()
```

Con este codigo logre solo loguearme y cambiar de url. Dentro de la URL nueva necesito hacer click en: `<a id="clone-btn" href="javascript:void(0);">Duplicate</a>`

Pense en hacer click en el href pero no puedo entonces quizas puedo seleccionarlo a travez de el ID. 
Para ser mas claro, necesito poder clickear `clone-btn`

Gracias

Comment: No conozco python, pero, como veo que usas javascript, podrías crear una función que lea el querystring de una URL y, cuando se cumpla la condición, ejecute el código que tienes en tu botón `clone-btn`.

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave tenes idea como puedo hacer para ejecutar el boton `clone-btn`??

Comment: Martin que yo sepa (la verdad es que no conozco esta librería en profundidad) mechanize es un parser html con algunos extras, si intentas emular la pulsación de un botón html necesitas ejecutar el código javascript asociado a ese botón y mechanize no ejecuta código js. Una opción es crear una función en Python que haga lo que hace el js asociado al botón (envio formulario, etc) y en vez de "pulsar" el botón ejecutas ese código. Otra opción es emular un navegador completo con  Selenium y PhantomJS.

Comment: @FJSevilla La idea es en realidad no usar Selenium ya que quiero hacerlo todo desde la terminal. Muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Cuando dependes de js, se hace imprescindible que sea un navegador quien controle el renderizado de la página web. Lo habitual para esta tarea es usar selenium o playwright. Y todo se puede hacer desde un script de python, no hace falta que se vea ninguna ventana.

Answer (score 0):

Esta es una idea de cómo podrías hacerlo de otra forma - usando javascript.

---

Dentro de la URL = nueva página, cambia el `<a></a>` por un input.

Ejemplo:

```
<input type="button" id="myBtn" onclick="clickAEsteBoton();">Este es un botón</input>
```

Luego en esa misma página en donde tienes el botón, colocarías esta función:

```
function clickAEsteBoton() {
    // Coloca aquí tu código javascript que desees ejecutar.
    // Si quieres abrir una nueva ventana, usa por ejemplo:
    window.open('https://es.stackoverflow.com');
}
```

Para llamar a este función, invoca la función en el `document.ready`, así:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    clickAEsteBoton();
});
```